# Are there any Qt specific profilers around?

Tags: qt, profiling, profiler

are there any profilers which work well with Qt? I'd prefer free profilers for windows but any hint is appreciated.

I tried "Very Sleepy" and it works but I cant convince it to demangle the method names. Maybe I'm just doing wrong? Any pit-falls I'm not aware of?

Thank you very much!

Here's a screnshot of Very Sleepys output:
[image]

Comment: Those method names having nothing to do with moc. Those are the usual mangled C++ symbol names you get with every C++ program, with Qt or without. Check if there is an option to demangle c++ symbols.

Comment: As I thought: I did wrong. However, I'm still unable to see clear text method names, there is no such option. On the other hand, a few of these methods are already demangled.

Comment: the demangled ones are apparently C functions, at least the onces in the screenshot. If you use mingw, maybe there is some incompatibility in the symbol names to MSVC and your profiler only supports demangling of MSVC-style C++ functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I happily use [gprof](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Profiling_with_GNU_gprof) from gcc. It's inside the [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) package for Windows.

Comment: I thought QT added funny keywords to the C++ text.  How does gprof handle that?